# Doesn't get Crash Report in Crashlytics?

Tags: ios, swift, crash-reports, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

Friends I am integrate Crashlytics using Fabric SDK. According to steps follow and Adding `Fabric` and `Crashlytics` framework in project. also adding code in AppDelegate as below.

```
Fabric.with([Crashlytics()])
```

after make a `IPA` file of APP and Distribute on Fabric and invite to Client. Client Download the IPA. He say App is Crash on device. But In Crashlytics doesn't get any crash report.

please help me what is missing, I doesn't get any Crash report.

[image]

Comment: May be the reflation of crash report that take some time to update at crashlytics.

Comment: Contact the support of the product. They are the right people to help you with that.

Answer (score 1):

If the application is crashing at the launch of the application then it will not be reported else it will be reported.

To cross check you can do force crash in Crashlytics.

Refer this [link](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/92522-is-there-a-quick-way-to-force-a-crash-)

Comment: No, I am Check to put code for Crash in Another ViewController, Although doesn't get crash.

Comment: I have updated my answer.. Try to do force crash.. If that works then you have integrated it successfully else there might be issue in integrating it in your app..

Comment: [[Crashlytics sharedInstance] crash]; is added in my viewController and Apps is Crash. But not get crash report..

Comment: Got the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have added the API Key and the Build Secret CORRECTLY in your Run Scripts.

1. You can find the API Key and Build phases in your Crashlytics account here
   [image]
2. Go to Xcode Project > YOUR TARGET > Build Phases > Run Script.
   ADD the Command as shown below replacing your API Key and Build Secret.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

From Xcode 7. By default in build setting -> enable bitcode is set to YES.
You need to make it NO. And then check.

This works for me. As per my Reading app need to send the crash reports to fabric. But if the Enable bitcode is YES then you need to download the DYSM file from Xcode and upload it manually to fabric.

check [Advanced Fabric setting](https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/advanced-setup.html)